Regressions in potty-training
This summer we went through potty-training with our daughter (26 months at the time). I had the feeling it was still a bit early for her (she wasn't showing much interest) but decided to do it anyway because it was a moment where I could be close to her and give her a lot of care and attention. She picked up easily enough and in 3-4 weeks she was diaperless. We used to take her out, at the park, in the car for longish trips without issue. She was staying dry during afternoon naps and most nights too.
Then in September she went back to daycare (she went last year too and never had any issues there) and she had a massive regression. We were expecting a bit of going backwards but it's been massive, she would not hold anything at all and wet herself even every 1/2h. Together with the daycare staff we tried to hold the line and not going back to diapers when she's awake (we had to put the nappies back for the afternoon and night) but in the end it was untenable and back to diapers she went. I still tried to keep her without at home in the afternoon because I felt badly for her to let her lose a competence that way.
However, a couple of weeks ago I kept her at home for a few days because she had a bad cold and by the end of the week she was back to the level she was at this summer. She would hold the pee for much longer, tell me if she needed to poo or pee and when I took her she would be dry/clean and go in the toilet. In short it seemed like it had "clicked" with her and she was toilet trained again and out of the regression.
Then she went back to daycare and, in 4 days time, she was regressing again as badly as before. She regularly poos in her pants every day and wets herself multiple times in a few hours span.
I am at my wits end and I don't know what to do. The daycare seems clearly to be the problem, but she does not show any obvious issue there. She seems to go happily enough, she doesn't cry and when we go and fetch her she is playing happily with the other kids.
More context: she is our second child, she is a very good-natured girl, she was always calm, kind and well-adapted (unlike her older brother) even though now she is entering the terrible twos and it shows in many respects.
Has anybody gone through something similar? Do you have any suggestions?

We had a small potty that would play a song when detecting liquid in it. For my son it was quite fun to be on it. He was diaper free at 30 month for the day and 6 month later as well over the night.

Regarding the regression when at the daycare, is there any chance that she is having too much fun playing to a) notice she needs to pee/poop and b) missing out part of the fun while sitting on the potty to do a proper job of it?

@BartvanIngenSchenau the first regression started in that manner (she was too distracted to leave play to go) but then morphed into something more extreme. E.g. she would go and pee in the toilet and then after 1/2h pee in her pants, like she has completely lost the control she previously had.

@cecilian-MonicaWasMistreated, that does sound a bit like she went back to play after emptying only half her bladder and not recognizing that she still needed to pee.

Yes, this is probably a common experience. I can offer my case as an example, but my general advice is to accept that this may be a long journey and that you may be dealing with potty learning for more than a year. Many cycles of success and regression may be necessary.
Here are some good answers for a similar question.
Our Case
We also started potty training (or "potty learning" as some newer guidelines call it) when my son was around 2 years and 3 months old and did it during a short vacation where we were home for about 5 consecutive days. We followed a popular modern procedure for doing it: low pressure, no bribes, and using diapers only at naptime and bedtime. We would just tell him calmly that pee and poop go in the potty when he did them in his pants.
This seemed to work at first, and we were optimistic about him shortly being fully potty trained in a few weeks. As in your case, he seemed be doing well both at home and at daycare. He even had a couple days at daycare and at home with no accidents. However, this did not last and he began to have 5 or 6 "accidents" some days at home. We kept him out of diapers except when sleeping at home, but the daycare's policy was to put him in a diaper after two "accidents" in a day. I put "accident" in quotes because "accident" seems to imply that urinating or defecating in his pants was fully unintentional. I think that he was often aware that he was peeing and pooping in his pants, but not motivated enough to stop what he was doing and go to the potty. Of course, immature muscle control may have also played a part.
We tried many things, such as 30 minute reminders, allowing him to watch videos that he liked on the potty, and suggesting that he might have "surprise pee" when he said that he didn't need to try the potty after an hour since the last pee. These things all had temporary initial success followed by regression, but there was also a slow overall improvement that kept us working at it.
We tried to never apply too much pressure to avoid negative associations with the potty or accidents. Even if it weren't a bad idea, you cannot force a kid to sit on the potty if they outright refuse.
I feel somewhat confident that he would have been potty trained much sooner if he had not been going to daycare. Several months after beginning, we took a family vacation for over 2 weeks. He improved considerably during this time, and seemed to be accident-free by the end. Unfortunately, he completely regressed again (both at home and at daycare) after returning to daycare.
The Endgame
So we had more than a year of him being sent home with soiled clothes wearing a diaper from daycare almost every day (although the frequency of good days improved) and constantly carrying several wipes and extra pairs of underwear and pants (and also shirts and socks for some leaks). I cleaned up poopy messes in parks and other awkward places without the benefit of a bathtub more times than I can count.
Finally, at about three and a half, we decided to implement a sticker chart where he would earn stars that would get him sugary treats, an episode of his favorite show, or small toys. This seems to be contrary to recommended practice, but we were out of ideas and this seemed to motivate him. However, I'm a scientist, so I have to say that there is no way to know for sure whether this intervention helped or whether there was some other change (muscle control, cognitive development, influence from other kids in his daycare room, etc.) that truly drove the improvement. Probably there were multiple factors.
He started to go several days between accidents, so we started fading out the sticker chart over several weeks (more stickers needed for a reward). He started to forget about putting stars on the chart and seems to have forgotten about what he is supposed to be earning next (for a month or so, the next prize on the sticker chart was constantly on the front of his mind). We traveled last week, and we haven't put the sticker chart back up. He hasn't commented on it yet. So I think that we might have finally arrived. I'm still not convinced we won't have a regression, but I think we maybe out of the woods now.
Takeaways
So what can you learn from this? I'm really not sure. I think we probably started too early. I think he got accustomed to having wet underwear and poop in his underwear before he was truly capable of making it to the potty every time (especially in a daycare environment). Did we suffer unnecessarily for months by not putting him in diapers and insisting on sending him to daycare in underwear, despite getting piles of dirty laundry every day? Maybe we should have just given up and tried again after he turned 3? Maybe we should have started the sticker chart earlier? I don't know.
Some kids became potty trained within in a few weeks at 2 and a half. I know of some kids who still go to daycare in diapers at 4. These outcomes are all probably within the normal variation. Our pediatrician said that we should have a talk if he wasn't potty trained by 3 and a half. You should probably chat with your pediatrician about it at your 3-year check-up.

Thank you, while your answer is dashing my hopes that there could be a simple solution, on the other hand I'm reassured that our experience is not unique. I was a bit worried that a regression so complete may be related to something that was stressing her a lot. It's probably the curse of the scientist, always trying to look for patterns in anything :)
I'll wait a couple more days and then accept your answer, more than for the solution, because your experience is very relevant.

Yes, I agree it's important to try to understand why you might be having the regression. I think the biggest deficiency of my answer is that I don't talk much about the child's feelings, which are at the root of potty learning. The answer by @MiniMum discusses some reasons why daycare seems to cause regressions. I think the first regression is common. At first the potty is something new, and they get excited about it. Once that excitement has worn off, some kids don't see much of a reason to stop what they are doing and go to the potty and developing that motivation can be very hard.

As someone who just went through potty training for two boys, all I can say is that for my eldest I spent a few years stressing out about it, coming up with plans and interventions, and trying to 'figure it out'. And through all that he mostly just went at his own pace. There were regressions, there were times he progressed, but for the most part he did it all in his own time, at his own pace.
The only intervention that ended up being actually useful for my eldest was to put him back in diapers and take all the pressure off when he was about 3.75. This was recommended to us by our doctor, and after that point he made a lot of progress. (don't be afraid to put your kid back in diapers if she hits a wall - take a break, really).
For my youngest, we did basically nothing and he's fully potty trained at two and a half. So in the case of our boys personality was a huge factor. Our eldest doesn't care, our younger one does. What my wife and I have done has had almost no impact.
This is mostly a long way of saying that you have much less control over the outcome of your kids potty training than you think, and you'll save yourself a lot of stress if you relax and just let it happen. To me the most critical aspects of what you can do are the following:

Keep it positive, don't overreact to accidents, be neutral most of the time
Try to be encouraging, but don't be over the top about it

Outside of that, your girl is quite young being under three, so not having consistent results yet is quite normal and age appropriate. The fact that she's already had a good streak before regressing is a good sign. Just keep at it, keep it positive, and she'll figure it out.
It's definitely possible that she'll make a lot of progress soon, but bear in mind that for some kids the progress doesn't really happen until after age three. So be patient. And if you feel overwhelmed at any point don't hesitate to contact your doctor about it.
Hope this helps.

Great answer, +1. Although you've not cited any supporting literature, I just want to add that this approach is, in fact, supported by the literature, and, consequently, the American Academy of Pediatrics.

While I agree this is the nice and positive approach I still want to point out that the average age at which children finish their potty training varies significantly between countries and over time spans of a few decades. Saying a girl under three counts as young for potty training fits with the US today but ask your parents at what age you were potty trained or even at what age they were and you will see that answers will go as low as 12 months age as a typical age for potty training. I hav no idea what changed and whether this is something within parents power.

Thank you, this is good advice and I can see the wisdom in it. I guess if she had just faced difficulties from the onset I may have had a different attitude; my frustration comes from the fact that she was doing so well and then lost it. The last regression is what leaves me most puzzled/unsatisfied since she regained the skill and lost it again in a matter of days.

@quarague Probably at least partly due to changes in diaper 'technology' - a dirty diaper is less uncomfortable now than it was, so there is less motivation for the child to stop using them.

@cecilian-MonicaWasMistreated regressions are pretty normal and there are a lot of causes. Kids brains are constantly changing, re-wiring, forgetting old information, learning new information, growing etc. It's pretty normal for a two year to have accidents so really, what you're experiencing is common. My answer may seem to glaze over the point, but trust me on this one.. it hits the point exactly if you read closely. I asked many training questions over the past two years, I wish someone said this to me. Trust me on this.. just relax.

Is she able to go to the toilet independently or does she need someone to help her (adding a child seat, putting her on etc)? From the way you are describing it, it sounds like you have to help her to some extent, i.e. she tells you she needs to go, you take her to the toilet. There is no problem with that, as she is small, but it could mean that it is more difficult for her to do this at the daycare. Perhaps she feels less comfortable asking a different adult for help, compared with her parents. Perhaps the staff are busy and/or she's not communicating clearly for them, since parents understand their small children better than other adults do. Therefore, it could be less of a problem with the toileting itself and more to do with other factors.
You could try continuing with nappies at daycare and using the toilet at home where she is more easily able to get the help that she needs. Gradually she may start to ask for the toilet at daycare. Another option, if it's not already the case is to request an option at daycare that she can manage more independently, like keeping a potty in the bathroom that she can use herself. When my son potty trained, he was confused at first by wearing underwear, he thought he could use it as a nappy. It's not really practical for her to be underwear free at daycare but perhaps lightening the clothing in that area (e.g. skirt and underwear rather than trousers) might make it feel less nappy-like.
Good luck! She's doing very well for her age and she'll get there soon enough.

Thank you for your answer. Actually the puzzling part is that both regressions were "all around regressions" in the sense that she was doing well both at home and at daycare and then lost the skill completely both at home and at daycare.
You've given me something to think about though, she has a potty she can use independently but she's not fond of it and prefers the toilet (where she's not independent of course). So maybe we could try something to make her more interested about the potty and going on her own.

@cecilian-MonicaWasMistreated It's a matter of expectations.  If she has gotten use to using a diaper throughout the day she gets in that habit, which can move on to evening.  It's hard to remember to switch from "just don't worry about it, diaper will take care of it" to "pay allot of attention to your body signals" every day.  To help with this you can point out the difference, remind her she is home now and so were going to have no diapers like a big girl.  Make a big deal reminding her often at first when she transitions from school to home life that she needs to switch to paying attention

@dsollen Yes, it's certainly a problem, but the two times she regressed she came into an attitude of not caring at all where she goes. It's like she doesn't want to pay attention, no matter how much we praise, encourage her, or remind her that big girls go in the toilet
